# How many harmonics does this functions have?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How many harmonics do the functions $$\cos(100\sqrt{8} \pi n), \qquad \cos(800 \pi n), \qquad \cos(100(\sqrt{8}^3 \pi n)$$ have?

I am using complex exponentials.